# Google AdMob Integration issue in ios

Tags: iphone, xcode, admob

I have **two different UIViews**(on View controller's top and bottom) in **same Viewcontroller**,and i need to show same Ad in both UIViews. Currently i am adding GADBanner view object in both UIView as subview in that case only 2nd View in which added Google ad is display andn ot first one.is there any way to do that?

like there is 2 UIView, viewTop and viewBottom,

i have  GADBannerView *adBannerView ;

adBannerView initialization ,give Id and all process.....

Then, i am doing ,
                 [viewTop addSubview : adBannerView];
                 [viewBottom addSubview : adBannerView];

but it is adding only in viewBottom and not in viewTop.

Please help me if anyone know about it.